# Listar um range de números e somar um por um

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com essa dúvida não sei como começar, gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para somar um numero com outro de um range
por exemplo:

```
2 = 2
3 = 5
4 = 11
```

E assim por diante não estou conseguindo prosseguir, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço desde já.

Comment: A sua questão não está clara o suficiente. O que significam esses `2 == 2 3 == 5 4 == 11` Isso são comparações ou eram suposto ser somas ? Quais numeros somam com quais ? Dê um exemplo concreto de entrada e saída para que fique o mais claro possível.

Comment: simples , o programa tem que imprimir uma sequencia usando os numeros conforme vão sendo listados por exemplo: se mostrar o 5 o resultado da soma será 5 , agora se mostrar o 6 o programa tem que somar o 5 com o 6 resultando em 11 , depois ele tem que somar 5 6 e 7 dai resulta em 18 e assim vai

Comment: Nesse seu exemplo a soma termina quando ? Começa sempre em 5 ? O numero que a pessoa mete é o limite inferior da soma ou o limite superior ? Que regras são usadas para estabelecer cada um dos limites ? Esses limites são inclusivos ou exclusivos ?

Comment: Nesse caso o usuario não insere nenhum numero , o programa apenas roda mostrando os valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `sum` o código seria esse:

```
print(sum([1,2,3]))
```

separado por variáveis:

```
lista = [1,2,3]

soma = sum(lista)

print(soma)
```

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi a sua pergunta, queres somar todos os elementos de um range

use FOR junto ao range,

```
n_elementos = 5
soma = 0

for i in range(1,n_elementos+1):
    soma += i

print(soma)
```

o 'n_elementos+1' se deve ao range(x,y) ir de x até y-1

Answer (score 1):

Para isto podemos utilizar duas funções em python.

A funcão **range** que cria um iterável do intervalo de valores a partir dos parâmetros informados e a função **sum** que soma um iterável e retorna o resultado

segue um exemplo:

```
sum(range(1,5))
```

segue os links das documentações das funções

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum